# How to loop through multiple polynomial fits changing the degree

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

My code functions properly but I am repeating a block several times to vary the polynomial variable, degree.  I assume this can and should be looped to allow quicker iterations, but I'm not sure how to do it.  Prior to the code below I generate the train_test split which I keep for plotting.

After several iterations, I use np.vstack on the y_predictions to create a single array.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

### degree 1 ####
poly1 = PolynomialFeatures(degree=1)
x1_poly = poly1.fit_transform(X_train)
                           
linreg1 = LinearRegression().fit(x1_poly, y_train)
pred_1= poly1.transform(x_prediction_data)
y1_poly_pred=linreg1.predict(pred_1)

### degree 3 #####
poly3 = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
x3_poly = poly3.fit_transform(X_train)
                                  
linreg3 = LinearRegression().fit(x3_poly, y_train)
pred_3= poly3.transform(x_prediction_data)
y3_poly_pred=linreg3.predict(pred_3)

#### ect... will make several other degree = 6, 9 ...
```

Comment: Did you try a simple for loop?

Comment: Yes but I must have been doing it wrong or had another problem.  I was getting an error and under impression I couldn't keep re-using linreg without indexing it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend collecting your answers in a dictionary, but I created a list for simplicity.

The code iterates over i, which is the degree of your polynomials. Trains the model, etc..., then collects its answers.

```
prediction_collector = []
for i in [1,3,6,9]:

    poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=i)
    x_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_train)
                               
    linreg = LinearRegression().fit(x_poly, y_train)
    pred= poly.transform(x_prediction_data)
    y_poly_pred=linreg.predict(pred)

    # to collect the answer after each iteration/increase of degrees
    predictions_collector.append(y_poly_pred)
```

Comment: Thank you.   This works great.  There's one typo, a plural 's' on predictions.  Still an upvote from me.

Comment: @Glenn No problem, this is basic coding stuff. let me know if you want me to help you on how to make it look better by collecting the answers into a dataframe or dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for the offer.  I was able to work with the lists, so I am all set for the time being.  The example you provided helped me answer a few other questions too.  Thanks again.  This was very helpful.

Comment: No problem youre welcs